# "Il me parle français" ou "Il me parle en français"?

Tags: expressions, prépositions

Si je parle une langue X, par exemple le français, je peux dire, de façon générale, que *Je parle français.* Par contre, si quelqu'un parle avec moi en utilisant cette langue, est-ce qu'on dit *Il me parle français.* OU *Il me parle **en** français.*?

Est-ce que ça change en fonction de la situation: *parler* en general (*Son père lui parle français.*) ou dans une situation spécifique (*Il m'a parlé français, afin d'être compris par tout le monde.*)

Y-a-t-il des changement où s'agit-il d'une action réciproque : *Nous nous parlâmes (en) français.* ?

Comment: @jlliagre Merci pour le link: la question semble différent au première regard, mais ta réponse clarifie tout.